Gradle build fails in Flutter project
I'm working on a Flutter project and trying to run it on an Android emulator. However, I'm encountering an issue when I try to build the project using Gradle. The build fails with the following error:

My file app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') ?: '1'
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') ?: '1.0'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace 'com.semenov.canada'

    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.semenov.canada"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
//        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
//        versionName flutterVersionName
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "com.semenov.canada"]

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

//flutter {
//    source '/Users/skv/Apps/Apps/canada'
//}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}


My file android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-kotlin:8.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Please help. I don't know what else to change to get the project running. I've already lost a week on this.
I tried to fix the error: 'You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block.' I changed the build.gradle files, versions, and ended up breaking everything.

do you have a working internet connection when you have tried to build this?

Gradle version in some projects is like this
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'


You must follow this documentation
You have command lines to delete from both gradle files.
